# Two divs containing lists next to each other - not working on IE

Tags: html, css

Hi all and let me apologize in advance if this question has already been asked. It is probably trivial for all of you but I have never really dealt with CSS too much as my job has not required it up to now.

So to illustrate the problem, I will post the code first. Here is the HTML part:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Panel3" CssClass="topPanel">
                      <h2 style="margin-left:30px">Summary</h2>
                  <div class="column">
                    <ul>
                        <li><label for="LoanNo" class="Labels3">Loan Id</label> <input runat="server" type="text" id="LoanNo" class="TextBoxes-Small" readonly="readonly" /></li>
                        <li><label for="OrigLoanId" class="Labels3">Originator Loan Id</label> <input runat="server" type="text" id="OrigLoanId" class="TextBoxes-Small" readonly="readonly"/></li>
                        <li><label for="LoanStatus" class="Labels3">Loan Status</label> <input runat="server" type="text" id="LoanStatus" class="TextBoxes-Small" readonly="readonly"/></li>
                        <li><label for="LockStatus" class="Labels3">Lock Status</label> <input runat="server" type="text" id="LockStatus" class="TextBoxes-Small" readonly="readonly"/></li>
                        <li><label for="Channel" class="Labels3">Channel</label> <input runat="server" type="text" id="Channel" class="TextBoxes-Small" readonly="readonly"/></li>
                    </ul>
                 </div>

                 <div class="column">
                    <ul>
                        <li><label for="WWProgram" class="Labels3">WinWater Program</label> <input runat="server" type="text" id="WWProgram" class="TextBoxes-Small" readonly="readonly"/></li>
                        <li><label for="WWProduct" class="Labels3">WinWater Product</label> <input runat="server" type="text" id="WWProduct" class="TextBoxes-Small" readonly="readonly"/></li>
                        <li><label for="trLockDate" class="Labels3">Lock Date</label> <input runat="server" type="text" id="trLockDate" class="TextBoxes-Small" readonly="readonly"/></li>
                        <li><label for="trLockExpDate" class="Labels3">Lock Expiration Date</label> <input runat="server" type="text" id="trLockExpDate" class="TextBoxes-Small" readonly="readonly"/></li>
                        <li><label for="trPurchaseDate" class="Labels3">Purchase Date</label> <input runat="server" type="text" id="trPurchaseDate" class="TextBoxes-Small" readonly="readonly"/></li>
                        <li><label for="trCancelDate" class="Labels3">Cancel Date</label> <input runat="server" type="text" id="trCancelDate" class="TextBoxes-Small" readonly="readonly"/></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

</asp:Panel>
```

and here is the CSS:

```
.topPanel {
border-bottom: 1px solid #0055a8;
float:left;
width:100%;
padding-bottom: 15px;
}

ul, li{
margin:0;
padding:0 0 0 15px;
list-style-type:none;  
}

.column{
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}

    .Labels3 {
        float:left;
        display:inline-block;

        text-align: right;
        font-family: 'Segoe UI';
        font-size:15px;
        color: #0055a8;
        margin-left:10px;
        margin-bottom:6px;
    }

    .TextBoxes-Small {
        margin-left:5px;
        font-family: 'Segoe UI';
        font-size: 14px;
        width:175px;
        border-color: #0055a8;
        border-width: 1px;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
        border-top-right-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
        border-top-left-radius: 5px;
        vertical-align:central;
        padding-left:5px;
        margin-bottom:3px;

        float:right;
        display:inline-block;
    }


h2 {
font-family: 'Segoe UI';
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #0055a8;
        margin-left: 20px;
}
```

And here are the results, visualized:

- Chrome

https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9VAw.png

- IE

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qwedw.png

The result also looks fine in Firefox. I am fairly certain that the floats and inline blocks are causing the problem, but like I mentioned before, I am very far from properly understanding the intricacies of CSS and browser tricks, so I will greatly appreciate if somebody can point out to me what is the best way to fix this. Also please excuse the poor design of the blocks, I am certain that there are much better ways to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a really simple example of how this can be simplfied. Let me know if I can further explain :)

Basically I removed your `<ul>` and now the labels are floated to the left and then cleared to line every input up perfectly. Should work in every browser.

Have a fiddle - [Fiddle Link!](http://jsfiddle.net/BuSZn/2/)

HTML

```
<h2>Summary</h2>

<div class="column">
    <label for="LoanNo" class="Labels3">Loan Id</label>
    <input runat="server" type="text" id="LoanNo" class="TextBoxes-Small" readonly="readonly" />
    <label for="OrigLoanId" class="Labels3">Originator Loan Id</label>
    <input runat="server" type="text" id="OrigLoanId" class="TextBoxes-Small" readonly="readonly" />
    <label for="LoanStatus" class="Labels3">Loan Status</label>
    <input runat="server" type="text" id="LoanStatus" class="TextBoxes-Small" readonly="readonly" />
    <label for="LockStatus" class="Labels3">Lock Status</label>
    <input runat="server" type="text" id="LockStatus" class="TextBoxes-Small" readonly="readonly" />
    <label for="Channel" class="Labels3">Channel</label>
    <input runat="server" type="text" id="Channel" class="TextBoxes-Small" readonly="readonly" />
</div>

<div class="column">
    <label for="WWProgram" class="Labels3">WinWater Program</label>
    <input runat="server" type="text" id="WWProgram" class="TextBoxes-Small" readonly="readonly" />
    <label for="WWProduct" class="Labels3">WinWater Product</label>
    <input runat="server" type="text" id="WWProduct" class="TextBoxes-Small" readonly="readonly" />
    <label for="trLockDate" class="Labels3">Lock Date</label>
    <input runat="server" type="text" id="trLockDate" class="TextBoxes-Small" readonly="readonly" />
    <label for="trLockExpDate" class="Labels3">Lock Expiration Date</label>
    <input runat="server" type="text" id="trLockExpDate" class="TextBoxes-Small" readonly="readonly" />
    <label for="trPurchaseDate" class="Labels3">Purchase Date</label>
    <input runat="server" type="text" id="trPurchaseDate" class="TextBoxes-Small" readonly="readonly" />
    <label for="trCancelDate" class="Labels3">Cancel Date</label>
    <input runat="server" type="text" id="trCancelDate" class="TextBoxes-Small" readonly="readonly" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    font-family:'Segoe UI';
    color: #0055a8;
}
h2 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.column {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 400px;
}
.column label {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 160px;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
}
.column input {
    margin: 0 0 10px;
}
.TextBoxes-Small {
    font-size: 14px;
    border: solid 1px #0055a8;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, worked like a charm! I am sorry that I do not have enough reputation to upvote your answer..